# How can I render an object in HTML?

Tags: html, json, angular

So in my angular project, I want to render an array of product object.
I was able to render it as JSON object:

```
    <td>{{o.products |json}}</td>
```

And for example this one of the outputs:

```
    [ { "id": 4, "name": "Forever", "description": "Because you suffer a lot physically and morally, we will not let you suffer financially.\n• Lump sum payment: Up to US $500,000 paid immediately upon diagnosis of any covered 32 critical illnesses.\n• Worldwide coverage: Giving you the assistance you need even if you move to another country.\n• Telemedicine and e-counsultancy through World Care International: Access to free expert care from world-renowned medical centres in the US specialising in your condition.", "price": 300, "logo": "assets\\download(5).jpg", "category": 1, "image": "assets\\forever.jpg" } ]
```

Now what if I only want to show the name attribute and not the whole product attributes. How can I do that?

Comment: `<td>{{o.products.name |json}}</td>`?

Comment: Why do you need an array if you only got one object in it?

Comment: @HereticMonkey nooo

Comment: @Arcteezy no I have cases where there is more than one object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ngFor directive, to create a for-loop that iterates over all products, and print only the product name:

```html
<td *ngFor="let product of o.products">{{product.name}}</td>
```